# How to Use multiple colors in map.plot kwargs for python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am trying to plot lat and long of incidents data on a map.

In this code, I need ten different color arguments to make it work, I have run out of colors. 
How do I address the issue?

```
lon=[]
lat=[]

def getcolor(c):
    if c in [1970,1980,1990,2000,2010]:
       return 'bo'
    if c in [1971,1981,1991,2001,2011]:
        return 'go'
    if c in [1972,1982,1992,2002,2012]:
        return 'ro'
    if c in [1973,1983,1993,2003,2013]:
        return 'co'
    if c in [1974,1984,1994,2004,2014]:
        return 'mo'
    if c in [1975,1985,1995,2005,2015]:
        return 'yo'
    if c in [1976,1986,1996,2006,2016]:
        return 'ko'
    else :
        return 'wo' # I have run out of color arguments 


def map_year(year):
    count=year
    while count>year-10:
        lon=pd.Series(df.longitude[df['iyear']==count])
        lat=pd.Series(df.latitude[df['iyear']==count])
        x,y = map(lon.tolist(),lat.tolist())
        map.plot(x, y, getcolor(count), markersize=6)
    plt.hold(True)
    count=count-1
    plt.show()

map_year(2016)
```

***update*** 
Thank you for your inputs..
Now I changed the color format to rgb tuples in getcolor function and edited the plot command to :

map.plot(x, y,color=getcolor(count), markersize=6)

The output is 
[current ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTuFl.png)

the desired output in ten different colors of markers is 
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Tv7.png)

Advice please

Comment: Use rgb values instead

Comment: try color = getcolor(count)

Comment: Markers' type is fixed? Always 'o'?

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty, have done that

Comment: Thanks @JayParikh have done that. map turns out a maze of lines instead of spots, can you help figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any color with the `color=` keyword argument, e.g. hex RGB strings like `'#5742FD'`.

Consult the Matplotlib documentation for details: [Matplotlib Colors](https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html)